# How many hooks is it advisable to create per class?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Is there a number for it? Has anyone experienced concurrency issues?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you cant create hooks in class based comp , only in functional components.

Also there's no such issue as how many hooks to be created in functions. it depends on your code how much re rendering is those causing if youre using `useState`

Comment: If the answer helped you do mark as accepted,  would be gladful